How to show these two functions are the inverses of each other?
The two functions in question are the $\text{dexp}_\Omega$ and $\text{dexp}_\Omega^{-1}$ operators, which are defined as follows:
$$ \text{dexp}_\Omega(C) = \Phi(\text{adj}_\Omega)(C) \\
 \text{dexp}^{-1}_\Omega(C) = f(\text{adj}_\Omega)(C), 
$$
where $\Phi$ and $f$ are defined as
$$\Phi(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(i+1)!}z^i \\
 f(z) = \frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{B_i}{i!}z^i 
$$
and $\text{adj}_\Omega(C)$ is defined as the commutator $[\Omega,C]$. I tried to take the composition of the two functions, but got messy expressions which do not appear to simplify. What is the proof? Also, I see that $\Phi(z) \times f(z) = 1$; is this in anyway related to the fact that $\text{dexp}_\Omega$ and $\text{dexp}_\Omega^{-1}$ are inverses?
